# Multidimensional Data Stream

Tags: data-request, time-series, real-time

I am looking for a dataset containing **multidimensional** data streams. More specifically, data points such as:

(x1, y1, z1), (x2, y2, z2), (x3, y3, z3), ...

which are **ordered or have time-stamps**.

When I search, I usually find *time-series* data which is a sequence of a single attribute. For example: stock price of a company or temperature of a room.

However, I need an extended version of that which has more than one attribute. For example, something like a sequence of (temperature, pressure, volume) or (number of requests, cpu usage, bandwidth usage) matched together.

The only thing I have found is Intel Lab Data (http://db.csail.mit.edu/labdata/labdata.html). The issue I have with it is that it is very hard to interpret any result that you get from analyzing it.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find the following datasets which are close to the description above:

UCI Air Quality Dataset, the amount of each gas can be considered a dimension:
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Air+quality

UCI EEG Eye State Dataset:
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/EEG+Eye+State

US dollar exchange rate compared to other currencies, each one can be considered a dimension:
https://datamarket.com/data/set/4nhz/us-dollar-exchange-rate

Room Occupancy Detection Data Set:
http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Occupancy+Detection+

Ozone Level Detection Data Set:
http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Ozone+Level+Detection